# JPanels shrink when JFrame is resized

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I'm making a video player with VLCJ; above and below I have two JPanels to display some information, and in the middle I have the canvas where the video is played. The problem is that when I resize the JFrame, the JPanels shrink and the Canvas expands, but when I place a button instead of the Canvas nothing changes. Do you know how to mantain the JPanels size when the JFrame is resized using GridBagLayout?

**Snippet:**

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

  static Test frame;
  static Canvas canvas;
  static int video = 1;
  JButton button;

    public Test() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel followTo = new JPanel();
          gbc.gridy=0;
          gbc.weightx=1;
          gbc.weighty= 0.11;
        add(followTo, gbc);

        canvas = new Canvas();
          canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);  

//        button = new JButton();

          gbc.gridy=1;
          gbc.weightx=1;
          gbc.weighty= 1.02;
          gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(canvas, gbc);
//        add(button, gbc);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
          gbc.gridy=2;
          gbc.weightx=1;
          gbc.weighty=0.16;
        add(controls, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new Test();
          frame.setSize(1200-54,864);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // /* Comment when using JButton
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
          Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
          MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
          EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
            emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(canvas));
            emp.prepareMedia(url("Toulouse.mp4"));
            emp.play();
        // */
    }

    static String url (String video) {
        String mrl = new Object().getClass().getResource("/media/guide.txt").getFile();
        String url = mrl.replace("/", "\\").split("\\\\",2)[1].split("media")[0].concat("media\\"+video);
          return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] to demonstrate the problem. We don't have access to the VLC component so we can't test your code. Your "MRE" should use standard JDK classes to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Bro, I'm using VLCJ how you can help if you don't have it? You can download it ._.

Comment: We are not here to download 3rd party code. Your question is about sizing of components added to the frame. So it is your responsibility to post code that demonstrates your problem without using a 3rd party components. That way we can verify if the problem is with your code or the 3rd party component. This is basic problem solving. First you simplify the problem!

Comment: Please read tags

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when I resize the JFrame, the JPanels shrink and the Canvas expands,

Well you are telling us what is happening, but you haven't told us what you EXPECT should happen.

I would guess the problem is the way you are using the weighty constraints.

Based on the code provided I would suggest you should NOT use a GridBagLayout, but instead use a `BorderLayout`.

Then the code for adding the panels to the frame would simply be:

```
add(followTo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(controls, Borderlayout.PAGE_END):
```

Now as the frame size changes, all the space will be given to the component in the CENTER. The components at the top/bottom would remain fixed in height.

Note you should also NOT be using static variables in your code.

Comment: I expect that the JPanels mantain the size, I'm using static variables for a reason and i need the answer with the layout I'm using. Thanks anyway

Comment: *I'm using static variables for a reason* - there is no reason to use static variables other than they are needed because of a poorly designed class.

Comment: *I expect that the JPanels mantain the size* - and you were given two suggestions on how you might accomplish that. I can't test it for reasons I gave you above. Did you try both suggestions? If neither suggestion works, then you can eliminate that the problem is with the layout code and the problem is with how you are using VLCJ. That is how you problem solve. One step at a time.

Comment: Your solution works but the JPanel size isn't the same as the one that I have with GridBagLayout

Comment: And did you fix the weighty constraints? The top/bottom should have a weighty of 0, So the panel neither grows or shrinks as the frame size is changed.